# AquireTokenAsync with old access token ADAL

Tags: azure, xamarin, single-sign-on, access-token, adal

I am developing an app on Xamarin. I am trying to implement a single sign on across multiple apps. For this I authenticate the user first time with Azure AD using ADAL and user enters the credentials in the O365 page displayed by ADAL in the `AcquireTokenAsync()`.

```
var  authContext = new AuthenticationContext(ServiceConstants.AUTHORITY);
var  authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, ServiceConstants.CLIENTID, ServiceConstants.RETURNURI, param);
var apiAccessToken = authResult.AccessToken;
```

When successfully authenticated, I save the received token to a file which does persists even if the user uninstalls the app.

Now next time the user starts the app, I pass the saved token to the 
`AcquireTokenAsync()` as `UserAssertion`

```
//Pass old accessToken
var userAssertion = new UserAssertion(accessToken);
var authResult = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(resourceUri, ServiceConstants.CLIENTID, userAssertion);
```

This works as expected and the user is authenticated without showing the O365 login screen.

Now I want this same behavior when the user uninstalls the app and reinstalls it. In my case, when the user uninstalls and reinstalls the app, I try to get a fresh token in the same way by adding the saved token as `UserAssertion` to the `AquireTokenAsync()`. However I get an error like so :-

```
Invalid JWT token. Token format not valid.
```

I cross checked the Token via Postman and it is a valid token.

**EDIT**
[image]

Any idea on how I can resolve this? Or a better way I can implement the same? Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying the exact same file is read in both cases but it fails if the app is uninstalled/reinstalled? This should not affect the token and should work the same way in both cases. Question would rather be if ADAL library is storing its own stuff and you need to look at that as well.

Comment: I have also seen similar errors if the token was already expired.

Comment: Sorry for comment spam... but your way of getting the token seems to be ill-advised on Xamarin: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Right-usage-of-confidential-client-flows

Answer (score 1):

If you have got the refresh_token, we can use this token to acquire the access_token silently directly  via the RETS.

Here is a example for your reference:

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&refresh_token=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq...
&grant_type=refresh_token
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps
```

More detail please refer the link below.

[Refreshing the access tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code#refreshing-the-access-tokens)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I do not get a refresh token as they are no more returned with the response. I have posted a picture in my Question. Please have a look

Comment: It seems that you were developing with adal libary with version 3.X. This version of library will handle refreshing token using the token cache automatically. For your scenario, you can try the version 2.X like [2.29.0](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory/2.29.0)

Comment: I will try downgrading my adal version. Alternatively, can I try saving the AuthenticationContext and play around with it maybe? In my case if I just don't uninstall the app and still do the Renewal on every app launch, by passing the access token as the user assertion, it works fine. Only on the reinstall of the app, I get the invalid JWT token error.

Comment: I can not seem to downgrade my ADAL version as I am using it in my Xamarin app and my PCL

Comment: Since you mentioned that the code works when you doesn't' uninstall the app. I suggest that you track the request and compare the difference send by the two requests.